# Change Subpath Behavior in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, pen-tool, path-effects

When using the pen tool sometimes the path operations change from "exclude overlapping shapes" to "combine shapes".

Is there a way to change the subpath's operation from combine to exclude?

for example: i am tracing a donut. tracing the outside outline first, then the inner outline next. If the inner outline was set to combine shapes, when try to make a selection out of this shape, i get a whole circle. What I would like is to change the operation of the inner circle into exclude so that when I make a selection of the shape, I get an actual donut.